# Setting up a Ramdisk on WXP

Tags: windows-xp, ramdisk

I need to do some lossless screencapture, and I am bumping into the maximum speed of the I/O access.

I decided to add a ramdisk, but I found few freeware ones, but I ended installing the ARSoft one, but it plainly does not work (it is installed and all, saves my settings, but it do nothing actually...)

Can someone help me with that?

I am using Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) it is effective and easy to use.  It also allows an .img file to be created on shutdown so that you can then reload that later (Or open with another program).  Just remember to make sure that you have a UPS on your computer otherwise you would lose your changes to that drive on a power outage.

The free version is unsupported for WinXP, and will let you run it 30 times.  For 10 bucks you can get rid of the timer.

Here are my benchmarks from PassMark:

```
SEQ Read: 1118 MB/s
SEQ Write: 959 MB/s
RAN Seek + RW: 41.3 MB/s
Disk Mark: 76638
```